# Use The Fundamental Theorem of Contour Integration or otherwise to evaluate the following integrals. (If it can't be used state why)

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, contour-integration

a) $\int|z|dz$, where $\gamma(t) = 3e^{it} (0 \le t \le \pi)$;

b) $\int \cos z - z\sin z dz$, where $\gamma(t) = (−1 + 2t) + it (0 \le t \le 1).$

Comment: What did you try? Can you see, for example, that in (1) we have $\;|z|=3\;$ when $\;z\in\gamma(z)\;$ ?

Comment: I know that to use the Theorem that an anti-derivative must exist but I am having difficulty trying to find this. I am also unsure where the value |Z|=3 has come from

Comment: If you're going to do line integral on the canonical circle of radius $\;3\;$ , namely: $\;\{z\in\Bbb C\;|\;z=3e^{it}\;,\;\;t\in[0,2\pi]\}\;$ , then on this line $\;|z|=3\;$ ...right?

Comment: Yes I can see this. Do I need to show ∫ f(γ(z).γ'(z) dz ?

Comment: Note that there is no $\gamma(z)$. (I edited the question accordingly). $\gamma$ is a curve assigning to a real number $t$ the complex number $\gamma(t)$. — When @DonAntonio wrote "$z\in\gamma(z)$" he ment $z=\gamma(t)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some highlights:

$$z=3e^{it}\implies |z|=3\,,\,\,dz=3ie^{it}\,dt\implies \int_\gamma |z|dz=\int_0^\pi 3\cdot3ie^{it}\,dt=\ldots$$

The other one is a segment of straight line joining the point $\;(-i,0)\,,\,\,(1,1)\;$ in the complex plane, or if you prefer the complex notation: the point $\;-1\,,\,\,1+i\;$ , so directly:

$$(z\cos z)'=\cos z-z\sin z\implies\left.\int_\gamma (\cos z-z\sin z)dz=z\cos z\right|_{-1}^{1+i}=\ldots$$